# Dissapearing PHP Variables

Tags: php

I am creating a 3D Secure PHP Project. I am having a rather bizzare issue in that the "MD" code is going missing when re-submitting the Array of data

My code is as follows :

```
$paRes = $_REQUEST['PaRes'];
$md = $_REQUEST['MD'];

require "payment_method_3d.php";


x_load('cart','crypt','order','payment','tests');

/*
* For Debugging Purposes
* Only.

echo "The Value Of PaRes is : ";
echo $paRes;
*/

$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://www.secpay.com/java-bin/services/SECCardService?wsdl");

$params = array (
    'mid'           => '',
    'vpn_pswd'      => '',
    'trans_id'      => 'TRAN0095', // Transaction ID MUST match what was sent in payment_cc_new file
    'md'            => $md,
    'paRes'         => $paRes,
    'options'       => ''
);
```

It seems that the $_REQUEST['MD'] string seems to go missing AFTER the soap call. Although I am having difficulty print this out to the screen. The strange thing is the $paRes variable works without issue.

Any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: this is very hard to determine without all of the code, what is the value of $md after the soap call? is it possible that payment_method_3d has a $md variable?

Comment: `echo $md;` BEFORE the Soap call. Did it exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses guys.

What was happening was the include page was sitting in front of the request methods and causing issues loading the REQUEST methods to the page.

Answer (score 3):

Check your case.  PHP array keys are case sensitive. From this little bit of code it looks as if the request variable may be 'md' instead of 'MD'.

Try $md = $_REQUEST['md'];

Answer (score 1):

PHP array statements are case sensitive, so this should work:.... 
`$md = $_REQUEST['md'];`